# SQL 2012 - Using IF THEN ELSE to update/insert a record, with variable columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've been banging my head on this one for a little while, and I feel like I'm exceedingly close, but I'm running into a problem when I try to make things work.

So, for my purposes, I've got a multitude of databases that I'd be running this script on. Depending on the version of the database (we have multiple customers, not all have the latest and greatest version with all of the new tables/columns).

I have 2 scripts currently that's being used by my CSRs to update tables, but I'm trying to remove the human element for determining which script needs to be run (as you can guess, this project is the result of someone running the old script on a new database, which left all sorts of fun unintended consequences in our software).

That being said, I need my script to update my 'USERS' table, but the values that need to go into said table need to take into account the version I've got running.

So, for an example of what I'm doing, let's say I've got 2 versions, 1 and 2. 
In version 1, I have the following columns:

- UserID
- Password
- UserNbr
- UserLName
- UserFName

In version 2, I've added one additional column: UserTypeID

With this in mind, I can get a simple IF THEN ELSE script to print my version number like so:

```
IF ((select VersionName from versions where VersionID = (select max(versionID) from versions)) = '2')
PRINT 'VERSION 2'
ELSE PRINT 'VERSION 1'
```

This works without issue.

When I try to use the same logic to update my user records, I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'UserTypeID'.

It seems as though it's attempting to read the full script before it attempts to apply the logic (whereas in my ideal world, it would obey the logic before it attempts to validate if the script can be run). I've tried encapsulating the statement that's to be applied against the version 2 variant in parenthesis, but this gives the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Sample script I'm using for version 1:

```
DECLARE @Count int
SELECT @Count = UserNbr FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'TEST'

IF ISNULL(@Count, 0) = 0
BEGIN
    --TEST TestUser
    INSERT Users (userID, Password, UserLName, UserFName)
    VALUES (
    'TEST', 'Password', 'User', 'Test')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users SET Password = 'Password', WHERE UserID = 'TEST'
END
```

Sample script I'm using for version 2:

```
DECLARE @Count int
SELECT @Count = UserNbr FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'TEST'

IF ISNULL(@Count, 0) = 0
BEGIN
    --TEST TestUser
    INSERT Users (userID, Password, UserLName, UserFName, UserTypeID)
    VALUES (
    'TEST', 'Password', 'User', 'Test', 1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users SET Password = 'Password', WHERE UserID = 'TEST'
END
```

Here is what I've come up with that's giving the error:

```
DECLARE @Count int
SELECT @Count = UserNbr FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'TEST'
IF ((select VersionName from versions where VersionID = (select max(versionID) from versions)) = '2')
IF ISNULL(@Count, 0) = 0
BEGIN
    --TEST TestUser
    INSERT Users (userID, Password, UserLName, UserFName)
    VALUES (
    'TEST', 'Password', 'User', 'Test')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users SET Password = 'Password', WHERE UserID = 'TEST'
END

ELSE 
IF ISNULL(@Count, 0) = 0
BEGIN
    --TEST TestUser
    INSERT Users (userID, Password, UserLName, UserFName, UserTypeID)
    VALUES (
    'TEST', 'Password', 'User', 'Test', 1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users SET Password = 'Password', WHERE UserID = 'TEST'
END
```

Obviously I'm offering a stripped down version of things, but the logic and syntax is identical to what I'm using in my environment. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error messages also contain line numbers - you should better provide'em. By the way you have unnecessary comm `,` before `where` in your update statements.

Comment: And yes, server compiles the whole script at a time. So if you don't have required columns - it will fail. You have to use dynamic sql or to encapsulate logic into sp and install on your server the proper version of this sp.

Comment: The `MERGE` statement does exactly what you ask but you could also use two separate UPDATE and INSERT statements to upsert all values at once. You can find *existing* rows with an INNER JOIN between Users and a table or TVP of the new values, *new* rows with a LEFT JOIN. In general, whenever you think you need an IF for data, there is a simpler way to do it with a WHERE and/or JOIN

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will parse the query before execution. Using same script on Ver 1 environment will give you error on the UserTypeID as you have noticed.

One way is to code the INSERT statement as dynamic sql. That way the engine will not be able to parse the dynamic query and will not throw off the erorr.